# How to make a class serializable if it include a field of "Object"

Tags: java

```
public class A implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Object value;
    private Type type;
....
}
```

It includes "Object" which is not serializable, so class A will be rendered as not serializable.

"Object value" could be Integer, String..., depending on "Type type"

How to make A serializable? 
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Will "Object value" get lost (when de-serialing) if using "private transient Object value"? I don't want to lost it.

Is there a general serializable Object type?

Comment: Java has a specific keyword for this, transient.

Answer (score 5):

> "Object value" could be Integer, String...

Integer and String are both serializable. It will work. You don't need to do anything special to serialize them.

> Is there a general serializable Object type?

Yeah, Serializable:

```
private Serializable value;
```

Comment: I tried to send A as a message through network(to JMS queue) and got Not Serializable exception.

Comment: @user2179277 Then you were trying to serialize something else that isn't an Integer or String. But both Integer and String are serializable.

Comment: @user2179277 Are you perhaps confusing `int` and `Integer`? The first being a primitive and the second being a class.

Comment: @Takendarkk You can't assign an int to an Object variable without it becoming an Integer, so that cannot possibly be the cause of a "Not Serializable" problem.

Comment: I'm aware of the autoboxing. I just wasn't sure if the OP ran the _exact_ code he is showing.

Comment: @Takendarkk "I'm aware of the autoboxing." Then why did you ask the question? How did you imagine that OP could possibly be going wrong by confusing them when assigning either of them to an Object variable gives exactly the same result?

Comment: I'm not sure, hence the reason I asked.

Answer (score 2):

`transient` keyword servers that purpose

```
private transient Object value;
```

Other way is to make the Object static if it does not represent your instance. static variables are implicitly `transient`.

> Will "Object value" get lost (when de-serialing) if using "private transient Object value"? I don't want to lost it.

If you do not serialize the variable its values will be lost. Serialization saves the state of instance of a class. When the instance will be deserialized it will have Object value in it but it will be initialized to the default value i.e null. So yes the value will be lost which is anyway the purpose of making a variable transient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use transient keyword to skip the serialization of a field:

```
private transient Object value;
```

Comment: Thanks Juvanis. Will "Object value" get lost (when de-serialing) if using "private transient Object value"? I don't want to lost it.

Comment: @user2179277: A variable that won't be allowed for object serialisation. so that the state of the value will always be defaulted after the deserialisation.
For example a variable x's value is set to 9, it's default value is '0' say, when the object has been serialized having x's value 9, after deserialisation will be defaulted to '0'